# Correct understanding for the notation $GA,GA'$ in definition of free objects for non algebraic categories if $G$ is a forgetful functor?

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition, functors

The following are taken from "Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative" by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Definition for “free over an object with respect to a functor":}$  Let $G:\textbf{A}\to \textbf{B}$ be any functor, and  $B$ an object of $\textbf{B}.$  We say the pair $(A,\eta),$ where $A$ is an object of $\textbf{A}$ and $\eta:B\to GA$ is a morphism of $\textbf{B},$ is $\textbf{free over}$ $B$ $\textbf{with respect to}$ $G$ just in case $\eta;B\to GA$ has the couniversal property that given any morphism $f:B\to GA'$ with $A'$ any object of $\textbf{A,}$ there exists a unique $\textbf{A-}$morphism $\psi:A\to A';$ such that

Diagram 1

[image: Diagram 1]

We refer to $\eta$ as the $\textbf{inclusion of generators;}$ and call the unique $\psi$ satisfying the above diagram the $\textbf{A-morphic extension of } f$ (with respect to $G$).

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

If we let $\textbf{A}=\textbf{Top}$ and $\textbf{B}=\textbf{Set}$ in Definition above, and $G$ to be the forgetful functor.  We let $(A‚\tau_A),(A',\tau_{A'})$ be topological spaces which are objects standing for $A,A'$ respectively in $\textbf{Top}.$ Let $\psi:(A‚\tau_A)\to(A',\tau_{A'}),$ be a morphism such that $\psi\in \textbf{Top}((A‚\tau_A),(A',\tau_{A'}))$ and $G\psi\in \textbf{Set}(G(A‚\tau_A),G(A',\tau_{A'}))$ be the functor $G$ in $\textbf{Top}((A‚\tau_A),(A',\tau_{A'}))\xrightarrow{G\psi} \textbf{Set}(G(A‚\tau_A),G(A',\tau_{A'})).$ As a functor, it is defined on objects in $\textbf{Top},$ $(A‚\tau_A)\mapsto G(A‚\tau_A), (A',\tau_{A'})\mapsto G(A',\tau_{A'}).$  But because $G$ forgets the structure of the objects in $\textbf{Top},$ then $G(A‚\tau_A)=A, G(A'‚\tau_{A'})=A'.$ Also for the case of what $G$ does to morphisms, $G\psi=\psi.$ Now let $B$ be an object in $\textbf{Set},$ and $GA=G(A‚\tau_A)=A,\eta:B\to GA:=\eta:B\to G(A‚\tau_A):=\eta:B\to A.$  Similarly, $f:B\to GA':=f:B\to A'.$ I would like to know if my understanding of the $\eta$ map is correct given that $G$ is a forgetful functor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, this seems good. I would write $G(\psi:(A,\tau_A)\rightarrow(A',\tau_{A'}))=\psi:A\rightarrow A'$ to emphasize the action of the forgetful functor over the morphism $\psi\in\operatorname{morph}(\boldsymbol{Top})$, but regardless of this, your interpretation of the $\eta$ map is correct. The next step should be to give a particular example of $A, B$ and $\eta$ that satisfies your definition.

Comment: @Julian thank you for replying and sorry for my late response.  I know the existence of free object in the case of the category of topological space is the discrete topology. The thing is, I am not where it fits in the above definition.  What I mean is nowhere in the definition does it require I place a topology on any objects from $\textbf{A}=\textbf{Top}$ Also, If I am given $(A,\tau_A)$ as an object in $\textbf{Top},$  then $A=B\in\textbf{B}=\textbf{Set}.$  Lastly, I am not certain if $GA, GA'$ are suppose to be the same, if so, then it seems to be that $\psi$ should be the identity map....

Comment: $Julian ...also, I know that for the $\eta$ map, $B\subset GA,$ and so it is injective.  But does it also have to be surjective also?